# How to install Aerospike on Mac?

Tags: database, macos, aerospike

I tried following: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac/

and did following:

```
mkdir aerospike-vm

cd aerospike-vm

vagrant init aerospike/aerospike-ce
```

This creates `Vagrantfile` in the same directory.

---

Next I try:

```
vagrant up
```

Getting error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'aerospike/aerospike-ce' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'aerospike/aerospike-ce' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/aerospike/aerospike-ce"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

What is the proper procedure to install Aerospike on Mac?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of vagrant are you using ? Seems old vagrant versions have issues with url redirection after the vagrant cloud vs terraform (community vs enterprise) separation. The url should go to vagrant cloud for community edition. But it is going to atlas which gets redirected to terraform.

Answer (score 3):

I recorded this few months ago along with two other videos in this set. See if this youtube video helps you out:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qm42c0juam4&list=PLGo1-Ya-AEQDa32hFggyB0yIIOldxUFwv&index=3

Here is the output from my run:

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro-4:aerospike-vm piyush$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 piyush  staff   128 Apr  9  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 54 piyush  staff  1728 Jan 18 10:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 piyush  staff    96 Apr  9  2018 .vagrant
-rw-r--r--   1 piyush  staff  3029 Apr  9  2018 Vagrantfile
Administrators-MacBook-Pro-4:aerospike-vm piyush$ mv Vagrantfile Vagrantfile_old
Administrators-MacBook-Pro-4:aerospike-vm piyush$ vagrant init aerospike/aerospike-ce
==> vagrant: A new version of Vagrant is available: 2.2.3!
==> vagrant: To upgrade visit: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
Administrators-MacBook-Pro-4:aerospike-vm piyush$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   5 piyush  staff   160 Jan 31 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 54 piyush  staff  1728 Jan 18 10:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 piyush  staff    96 Apr  9  2018 .vagrant
-rw-r--r--   1 piyush  staff  3029 Jan 31 14:13 Vagrantfile
-rw-r--r--   1 piyush  staff  3029 Apr  9  2018 Vagrantfile_old
Administrators-MacBook-Pro-4:aerospike-vm piyush$
```

Comment: Hmm.. you did the same command as me but for you is not giving error.. not sure what it is..

Comment: Let me check in a bit.

Comment: You may have to reinstall vagrant - I recall getting that error -- i had to remove vagrant completely and re-install. Its a vagrant issue - nothing to do with aerospike.  I just retested on my system, it works just like the video.  Google the hashicorp issue and you will see other non-aerospike users ran into the same issue.  (Vagrant did a repo reorganization or something like that.)

Comment: Updated the answer.